# I want to call a Ksh script when clicked on button in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, unix

I wanted to call a ksh script present on a Unix server when i am clicking on a button.

I am doing all this on a unix server where i have all ksh and jsp scripts.
Actually what i wanted to do is i have one JSP page with one textbox (to enter host) and one button.

Once customer will enter host and clicks on button i want to call a ksh script located at same unix location taking this host name as an argument.

Please help me out with this.
It will be great if i will get any example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code which works:
but i have a batch file under that dir `c:\ named tang.bat.`
try to put some file there and it will run

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=null;
String cmd="c:/Tango.bat";
try{
p=r.exec(cmd);
InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
String line=null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
%>

<%= line %>

<%
}
p.waitFor();
}
catch(Exception e){
out.println(e);
}
System.out.println(p.exitValue());
%>
```

OTHERWISE try this one whatever you want

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=null;
String cmd="/home/shdir/runmms.sh";
try{
p=r.exec(cmd);
InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
String line=null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
System.out.println(line);
}
p.waitFor();
}
catch(Exception e){
out.println(e);
}
System.out.println(p.exitValue());
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a servlet on the backend and use an AJAX type of resource request to the Servlet.  Once your in the servlet you will execute the script either using the runtime: 
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your script");`

or using the [Process Builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) which would look like:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("Script name", "arg1", "arg2");
Map<String,String> args = pb.environment();
args.put("arg1", "Val1");
....etc.....
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Thank you !!
But is there any option to call this script in <form method="post" action="ksh script">  ??

Comment: JSP is a visualization language that is used to produce HTML via Java, HTML and Taglibs.  When you execute a post method, the browser is calling back to the server to a class that is linked in via the web.xml.  I don't think you can have a form action that executes a shell script.